# Calculate correlation coefficient for discrete random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, statistical-inference, correlation

From a population consisting of the numbers: $\lbrace 1,2 \ldots 10 \rbrace$, two samples are chosen from it without replacement. If the random variable denoting the first choice is X and the second choice is $Y$, what is the correlation coefficient ($\rho$) between $X$ and $Y$

Comment: does the distribution of $X$ uniform on $\{1, 2, \dots, 10\}$?

Comment: yes distribution is uniform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $X$ is uniform on $\{1, 2, \dots, 10\}$ we have 
$$
\mathbb E X = \frac{1 + 2 + \dots + 10}{10} = 5.5, \quad \mathbb{V}ar X = \frac{1^2 + \dots + 10^2}{10} - \mathbb E X^2 = 8.25.
$$
To compute the expected value of $Y$ write 
$$
\mathbb E Y = \sum_{x \in [10]} \mathbb E[Y ~|~ X=x] \mathbb{P}(X = x),
$$
where $[n] := \{1, 2, \dots, n \}.$ Let us first compute $\mathbb E Y:$
$$
\mathbb E Y = \frac 1{10}\left[\frac {1 + \dots + 9}{9} + \dots + \frac{2 + \dots + 10}{9}\right] = \frac{55}{10} = 5.5.
$$
$$
\mathbb Var Y = \frac 1{10}\left[\frac {1^2 + \dots + 9^2}{9} + \dots + \frac{2^2 + \dots + 10^2}{9}\right] - \mathbb E Y^2 = 8.25
$$
For $\mathbb E XY$ we have 
$$
\mathbb E XY = \frac{1}{10}\left[\frac{1 + 2 + \dots + 10}{9\cdot 10} \cdot \sum_{x, y \in [10] \setminus x} y \right] = 30.25.
$$
Hence, 
$$
\rho(X, Y) = \frac{\mathbb Cov(X, Y)}{\sqrt{\mathbb Var X \mathbb Var Y}} = \frac{30.25 - 5.5^2}{8.25} = 0. 
$$

As for me, it is counterintuitive that the answer is $0$ and I suspect that there must be much simpler solution.

Comment: the given answer is -1/9

Comment: did you manually do all the calculations?

Comment: yes, probably miscalculated something, but you got the idea

Answer (score 1):

We want to find
$$
\rho(X,Y) :=  \frac{Cov(X,Y)}{\sqrt{V[X]V[Y]}} = \frac{E[XY] -E[X]E[Y]}{\sqrt{V[X]V[Y]}}.
$$

#### Inference on X

Assume X is uniform on {1, 2, ..., N}, then
$$
Pr(X=x) = 1/N \\
E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^N Pr(X=i) \cdot i = \frac{N+1}{2}, \\
E[X^2] = \sum_{i=1}^N Pr(X=i) \cdot i^2 = \frac{(N+1)(2N+1)}{6},\\
V[X] = E[X^2] - E[X]^2 = \frac{N^2-1}{12}.
$$

#### Inference on Y

The conditional density (pmf) for Y given X is given by the fact that the two samples are taken without replacement
$$
Pr(Y=y|X=x) = \frac{1}{N-1} 1_{x\neq y}, \\
Pr(Y=y) = \sum_{i=1}^N Pr(Y=y|X=i)Pr(X=i) = \frac{1}{N} = Pr(X=x).
$$
Hence X and Y has the same marginal density, and thus the same mean and variance.
$$
E[Y]=E[X],\\
V[Y]=V[X].
$$

#### Joint inference X, Y

The joint density is
$$
Pr(Y=y,X=x) = Pr(Y=y|X=x)Pr(X=x) = \frac{1}{N(N-1)} 1_{x\neq y}.
$$

The product expectation
$$
E[XY] = \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N ij \cdot Pr(Y=i, X=j) = \frac{1}{N(N-1)} \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N ij \cdot 1_{i\neq j} = \frac{1}{N(N-1)} \left( \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N ij - \sum_{k=1}^N k^2\right) = \frac{(N+1)(3N+2)}{12}.
$$

#### Correlation

Finally we have,

$$
\rho(X,Y) := \frac{E[XY] -E[X]E[Y]}{\sqrt{V[X]V[Y]}} = \frac{E[XY] -E[X]^2}{V[X]} = -\frac{1}{N-1}.
$$

With N=2 as in your problem: $\rho(X,Y) = -\frac{1}{9} = -0.111..$

#### Short intuition

Intuitively, we expect a negative correlation. Consider the outcome space {1,2,3}, which has mean 2. If X is below the mean, e.g. X=1 (<2), then Y must be 2 or 3, which has a mean of 2.5 (>2), i.e. biased upwards. If X is above the mean, e.g. X=3, then Y must be 1 or 2, which has a mean of 1.5, i.e. biased downwards. So Y will be biased away from X, i.e. negative correlation.

In fact, the above calculations can be genralized further by considering $m \leq N$ draws (random variables) instead of two. Then the correlation between any two different draws is still $-\frac{1}{N-1}$, or formally $\rho(X_i,X_j) = -\frac{1}{N-1}$, for $i\neq j$ and $i,j \leq m\leq N$.